# iid random variables random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> In preparation for a course I am doing later in the semester I have been trying to brush up on some probability theory. But I am struggling with the following problem:
>
> Let $\{Y_n,n\geq1\}$ be independent identically distributed random variables with $\mathbb{P}(Y_1=1/2)=\mathbb{P}(Y_1=3/2)=1/2$. Define $X_0=1$ and $X_n=\Pi_{i=1}^n Y_i$ for $n\geq 1$. Show that $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n=0)=1$.

What I have done so far:
I believe I recognize a random walk type of problem and I believe $\{X_n,n\geq 1\}$ is a decreasing sequence of events, so I can use the continuity of probability and get:
$$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n=0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n=0).$$

But I am not entirely sure how to proceed. Or am I on the wrong path?

So my main problem is how do I formally show this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take the logarithm of $X_n$ to get a sum of iid variables. This represents a 1-dimensional random walk biased toward $-\infty$. You can show that it converges a.e. to $-\infty$, so the exponential of it will converge to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(X_n)$ is a non-negative martingale and so converges almost surely to a random variable $X_\infty$. An infinite product can only converge to a positive limit if the terms converge to 1, and since $Y_n$ can't possibly converge to 1, we conclude that $X_\infty=0$ almost surely.